# java.sql.SQLException: Unable to find a suitable driver for jdbc weka.experiment.DatabaseUtils.connectToDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:563)

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, weka

I'm trying to connect Weka to MS SQL DB via a weka experiment retrieve instance query and getting the below error

One thing to note here is I do not have any default port assigned for the MS SQL DB instance and below is my Databaseutil.props file contents

```
# database URL
jdbcURL=jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQL\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=MovieDatabase
# specific data types
string, getString() = 0;    
boolean, getBoolean() = 1;
double, getDouble() = 2;  
byte, getByte() = 3;      
short, getByte()= 4;      
int, getInteger() = 5;    
long, getLong() = 6;      
float, getFloat() = 7;    
date, getDate() = 8;      
text, getString() = 9;    
time, getTime() = 10;     
timestamp, getTime() = 11;

# map SQL Server data type to WEKA data type
# default mappings
varchar=0
float=2
tinyint=3
int=5
# values added manually
string=0
bigint=6
nvarchar=9
decimal=2
bit=1
```

Error:

> sql.SQLException: Unable to find a suitable driver for jdbc:sqlserver://MSSQL\sqlexpress:1433;authentication=NotSpecified;authenticationScheme=nativeAuthentication;xopenStates=false;sendTimeAsDatetime=true;trustServerCertificate=false;TransparentNetworkIPResolution=true;serverNameAsACE=false;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true;selectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive;packetSize=8000;multiSubnetFailover=false;loginTimeout=15;lockTimeout=-1;lastUpdateCount=true;encrypt=false;disableStatementPooling=true;databaseName=MovieDatabase;columnEncryptionSetting=Disabled;applicationName=Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server;applicationIntent=readwrite;
>      weka.experiment.DatabaseUtils.connectToDatabase(DatabaseUtils.java:563)
>      weka.experiment.InstanceQuery.retrieveInstances(InstanceQuery.java:658)

Comment: Do you have a suitable driver for MS SQL Server in your classpath? I don't know how Weka is started but I would think you need some JDBC driver jar to be present in the runtime classpath for this to work. Something like http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Yes, I have sqljdbc42.jar from Microsoft added to the classpath. I see that port number 1433 is getting appended which is not required for my connection, any thoughts?

Comment: You may need to load the driver class in order for it to register with the driver manager.
Can you add some code to your application (as soon as possible... before loading the JDBC driver is attempted): Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

Comment: well... on second thought. According to this (https://weka.wikispaces.com/databases) you should add the jdbcDriver property to your config file. So try adding jdbcDriver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver to your Databaseutil.props file.

Comment: and also... according to the documentation above, your props file should be named DatabaseUtils.props

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the jdbcDriver property to your DatabaseUtils.props file:

```
jdbcDriver=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same issue in my env. After remove the scope from the dependency (initially I put test) it works.